# Escaping the in-app browser in iOS apps

Tags: ios, safari, continuity

Most iOS apps that open web pages open them in in-app browsers. These are somewhat restrictive, in that they don’t support bookmarks (and hence bookmarklets) or Handoff (although they do support AirDrop). Is there a quick way to open them in the full Safari iOS app?

The Share Sheet doesn’t seem to have one built in. You can copy and paste the URL, but that’s quite a bit of precise tapping.

This seems like functionality a third-party extension could add pretty easily. Not interested in jailbreaking though.

[image: iOS Share Sheet in Circa app]

Comment: What app are you in?

Comment: The extension would have to come from Safari for it to open directly in Safari. It might be possible to have an extension that briefly opens it in a shell app that then immediately pops open Safari.

Comment: @tubedogg I think a simple app that bounces you into Safari is the right way to go. Wish it it existed.

Comment: @user24601 Does that matter?

Comment: It might. All in-app browsers are different.

Comment: @user24601 They are, but I think the Share Sheets are all the same. Each app needs to [individually implement](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-open-links-in-your-mobile-browser-instead-of-the-1657320067) opening in Safari right now, whereas I’d like the option in all apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Add to Reading List" to store the URL and then open it in Safari. Still not ideal, but less clumsy than the copy/paste option.

Comment: It’s still 9 taps by my count, when you include removing the item from your reading list.

Answer (score 0):

The share sheet is therapy to go. Use the ... control to have it open in safari or possibly a third party web app. If your share sheet doesn't allow Safari as a share, then you'll need to agitate to the maker of that app to add Open in Safari to their app or find another app to use that supports your needs to escape their browser.

The workflow app used to be a great choice for glue between apps, but since Apple bought it - we might either see it continue to be useful and change or absorbed into the iOS. Worst case, another workflow type app surely will arise to help stitch together apps that didn't think they wanted to be linked and automated.